# Arcgis server CreateReplica REST API of feature not working

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I created Feature class in enterprise geodatabase (SQLServer2014 express). Feature class is sync enabled and published successfully.
Now I can not generate offline geodatabase from Arcgis Android SDk.
I can see ' **Create Replica** ' from '**Supported Operations**' from 'http://xyz:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyFeature/FeatureServer'

I tried 'http://xyz:6080/arcgis/rest/services/MyFeature/FeatureServer/createReplica' rest api from feature service. it creates job but no results shown.
Server logs show following error

**Error executing tool.: ErrorMsg@SyncGPService:{"code":400,"description":""} Failed to execute (Create Feature Service Replica).**

Log source is 'System/SyncTools.GPServer'

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that there's nothing needed at the DB level where your data is stored. Taking the server out of the equation, can you run the [Create Replica](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-replica.htm) tool in ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro against the data source, and does it succeed? If that works (and other operations like Adds, Updates, Deletes etc.), then put ArcGIS Server back in the equation.

What are your ArcGIS Server log levels set at? It may be beneficial to up the logging level to Verbose or Debug, try to create the replica again, and consult the logs to see if more helpful information is returned.

You may also want to check and see if your version of ArcGIS Server needs to be patched. For example, at 10.5.1 there was a [patch](https://support.esri.com/en/Products/Enterprise/arcgis-server/ArcGIS-Server/10-5-1#downloads?id=7598) released specifically for Sync issues.

If all else fails, [Esri Support](https://support.esri.com/en/) may be a good place to find some help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the requirements for making your data available for offline use? See [this link](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/prepare-data-for-offline-use.htm) in the ArcGIS Server documentation.

Specifically you need to enable archiving and include Global IDs on the dataset, but there are more details at the above link.

For future reference, and in case that suggestion doesn't work, the [Esri GeoNet ArcGIS Enterprise](https://community.esri.com/community/gis/enterprise-gis/arcgis-enterprise) place is a good spot to ask these questions.

Comment: yes, I followed the requirements for making data offline available. So I am not facing issue in publishing service. My issue is when I request replica from published service.
I am unable to post question in 'Esri GeoNet ArcGIS Enterprise' community. They have some issue in question editor